# shmat returns error (void *) -1 in selinux enabled rhel environment

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, selinux, c++, shared-memory

**as per the documentaion:-**

*If SHM_RDONLY is specified in shmflg, the segment is attached for reading and the process must have read permission for the segment. Otherwise the segment is attached for read and write and the process must have read and write permission for the segment. There is no notion of a write-only shared memory segment.*

So here I am passing 0, which is as per the above statement will give read and write access ot shared memory.

**ipcs output:-**

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status

0x5304f6ab 98307      root       666        64         1
```

**C++ code of attaching to memroy**

```
    //Get shared memory for given shm_id
    uint8_t* mem = (uint8_t *) shmat(_shm_id, NULL, 0);
    
    if ((void *) mem == (void *) -1){
       // in selinux enable system I am keep on coming here, mem is alway 0XFFFFFFF..
        return -1;
    }
```

strange thing is that I am getting the right shared memory location when I pass SHM_RDONLY flag in shmat function, even though the permission of shared memory is read and write.

only difference here is memory is created by root and read other user like user1, but since 666 permision is given I don't think that can be an isssue not sure if selinux is causing some issue here.

Comment: The first thing you should do is look at your logs for any AVC/SELINUX messages; distros like rhel will even try to interpret them for you, telling you what you should do for the operation to be allowed.

Comment: Also check errno after `shmat` has returned -1.

Comment: @UncleBilly on running strace i got this 
shmat(262152, NULL, 0)                  = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: @UncleBilly in audit.log I found no denials as such only logs for sytemd service start and stop as I am runnning the process with systemd, to make the test app transition to httpd_t contex, because running with this contex is causing issue. when I run this application with normally i.e using having unconfined_t domain type, there is not issue I am able to get right address for shared memory.

Comment: @UncleBilly with flag SHM_RDONLY  I can read the memory i.e shmat doesn't return FFFFFF and EACCES error